# MS Teams List Card

Tags: microsoft-teams

Do [list cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#list-card) in teams still work?

I want to try out a simple list card with support for scrolling.
However, I cannot get it working in App Studio(Card Editor) or from the code.

I do not see any way of sending a list card using CardFactory as well.

Comment: List cards are supported in Teams. You cannot test them using App studio. Could you please share some piece of code that you have tried and share some screenshots of the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they definitely still do work, I happened to test one this morning. You're right though that App Studio's Card Editor doesn't support them though, and CardFactory doesn't have a mechanism for them either, so you either need to create the JSON object explicitly, or use a JSON string.

I'm using C#, so can't send you a code sample, but it should just be a case of making sure your final output matches the correct format for List Cards

Comment: Thanks, sending a json using MessageFactory.attachment() worked

Comment: great, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

The list card sample json is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#list-card

This cannot be tested in the Adaptive cards designer - https://adaptivecards.io/designer

I got this working by using the following code in Java

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.setContentType("application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.list");
attachment.setContent(createCardJson("ListCard.json")));
Activity act=MessageFactory.attachment(attachment);
```

We have to change the ListCard.json to just have the content part of the json (from the link above) stored with the file. The content type is set with the `attachment` object